# How to import a specific variation of an npm package

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, iscroll

I'm trying to use Cubic [iScroll Infinite Scrolling](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) with ES6 imports. I have the base IScroll working fine however I want to get to the extended functionality of Infinite Scrolling which is inside the repo. But have no idea how to import it.

I'm using the following to import the base. I've tried numerous others that all fail to import.

```
@import IScroll from 'iscroll'
```

Variations available include:

- **iscroll-infinite.js** <-- Trying to import this variation.
- iscroll-lite.js
- iscroll-probe.js
- iscroll-zoom.js
- iscroll.js

Answer (score 2):

Considering that I was using WebPack, after searching through the webpack.conf.js files i found that it was setup as this:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],

    // THIS LINE IS WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR:
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],

    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
    }
  },
```

So to get to the specific variations I imported using:

```
import IScroll from 'iscroll/build/iscroll-infinite'
```

This seems to be doing exactly what I expected which is loading the package from full path:

```
../node_modules/iscroll/build/iscroll-infinite
```

Comment: can you point out where the documentation for `import` lives? it is new to me.